# Does Azure let me FTP a WCF service for testing?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-storage

A few months ago I purchased a shared hosting plan to test our WCF service. This is what I do when I want to deploy and test the service:

- Build the WCF project in "Release" mode in VS2017.
- Go to "Release" folder in my Windows PC and copy all the files.
  FTP those files to the shared hosting plan.
- Test WCF service in browser.

Can this be done with Azure? In other words, instead of pasting/FTPing the files from my desktop to my current shared host, I will paste/ftp to an Azure folder.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

App Service supports FTP deployment. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-ftp).